# Laravel - HTML POST Form, page not found

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I am currently making this web app using Laravel where you add a new product to MySQL using a HTML form.

The problem is that it doesn't work when I press the "Add product" it shows me this:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/4c34432ff69857809476f78aea5c6582.png]

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="store" method="POST">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('product_name', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                        {{ Form::text('product_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('product_description', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                        {{ Form::text('product_description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('product_producer', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                        <select name="producator" class="form-control">
                            <option>Pick producer...</option>
                            @if(isset($marks))
                                @foreach($marks as $m)
                                    <option value="{{$m->producer_ID}}">{{$m->producer_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add product</button>
                </form>
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
    $products = DB::table('laravel_products')->select('product_name', 'product_about', 'producer_name', 'product_added')->get();
    $marks = DB::table('laravel_producers')->select('producer_ID', 'producer_name')->get();
    return view(
        'welcome', 
        compact('products'), 
        compact('marks')
    );
});

Route::get("index", "test@index");
Route::post("store", "test@store");

/*
Route::post('profile', 
    [
        'before' => 'csrf',
        function()
        {

        }
    ]
);*/
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\laravel;

class test extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view("welcome");
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Laravel;
        $user->product_name = Input::get("product_name");
        $user->product_description = Input::get("product_description");
        $user->product_producer = Input::get("product_producer");
        $user->save();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The database table looks like this:
[image: https://i.gyazo.com/a83407718f756df02effd8461547d223.png]

What I must do in order that when I press the "Add product" to insert the values from the fields into my database?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your console, does `php artisan routes` show that store is a valid route?

Comment: @Panamera Check my answer and let me it's work for you?

Comment: @mbozwood it shows: https://gyazo.com/e24b12d02fcf137b0f500c6bb6d0d6f5

Comment: What's happening if you change Route::post to Route::get ?

Comment: Same problem, the HTML form sends POST data and it doesn't find the location. I think I will go take pills for headaches because of this problem.

Comment: Lets try something else, as you are using the Form facade, try opening the form using the following: `{{ Form::open(['action' => 'test@store']) }}` and close using: `{{ Form::close() }}'. Let me know what that returns

Comment: @PanameraTurboS have you tried the solution of mbozwood ?

Answer (score 0):

As you facing error `NotFoundHttpException` means something went wrong with route, Try below change:
**Route**

```
Route::post("store", "test@store")->name('store');
```

**Blade**

```
<form action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">
```

**UPDATE**
Also need to add redirection into store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new Laravel;
    $user->product_name = Input::get("product_name");
    $user->product_description = Input::get("product_description");
    $user->product_producer = Input::get("product_producer");
    $user->save();

    //redirect into index view
    return redirect('index')->with('status', 'Produvt Added!');;
}
```

Comment: I edited so, but still says: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: got it...Let me check

Comment: @PanameraTurboS: Check my **UPDATE** answer

Comment: So problem, not found. I think the problem is a route or somewhere there. On the YouTube video that I followed worked.

Comment: In this video works. But not for me: https://youtu.be/cccUdsONu28?t=6m9s

Comment: @PanameraTurboS: Means still problem there, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's hiding somewhere from me.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense at all, the test.php exists, the store function exists, what is wrong...

Comment: @PanameraTurboS: don't get panic, let debug the code one by one:
`print_r($request->all());` add this as first line into `store` method and let me know the result

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd That wont work, the fact he cannot find the route, means that wont run because it's not getting inside the controller function

Comment: @PanameraTurboS: Last try: Move this route to the top of your routes file and ran `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I done so, it told me: Unable to prepare route [api/user] for .... (lost problem, I will go to learn Laravel from 0 to solve this problem).

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form your data is stored into database or not?. If it's storing the data into database then you need to load the view after storing the data and here as i can see after storing the data into database you didn't load the view that's because it's showed your page not found. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it must store in the database. How should I proceed ?

Comment: @HaqNawaz Actually, if he don't load the view, the page should be blank.

Comment: write the exit; statement after insertion the data it will show you a blank page. If you don't write the exit; then it will proceed the execution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should prepare the correct routes. I mean that yout try to save data by sending the post request through the route '/laravel/public/store', but your web.php file doesn't contain such route.

So, my first advice for you is to set the root directory on the right way ([enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration))

Comment: Yes it does: Route::post("store", "test@store")->name('store');

Comment: No, this is the problem. I don't see where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

//add CSRF_Field & change form action to {{route('store')}}

```
 <form action={{route('store')}} method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('product_name', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                        {{ Form::text('product_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('product_description', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                        {{ Form::text('product_description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('product_producer', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                        <select name="producator" class="form-control">
                            <option>Pick producer...</option>
                            @if(isset($marks))
                                @foreach($marks as $m)
                                    <option value="{{$m->producer_ID}}">{{$m->producer_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add product</button>
                </form>
```

//controller change it to producator not product_producer

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $user = new Laravel;
            $user->product_name = Input::get("product_name");
            $user->product_description = Input::get("product_description");
            $user->product_producer = Input::get("producator");
            $user->save();
        }
```

//route

```
Route::post("store", "test@store")->name('store');
```

Comment: Actually on the OP question the exception is NoFoundHttpException.
And not a TokenMismatchException. 
You are probably solving  a future issue. But based on the others answer, just changing `action="store"` to `action="{{ route('store') }}"` will not solve the problem.

Comment: okay, my bad..
i don't know if this is the issue, may i know how you run the server?
did u use "php artisan serve"?if u use that, i think you have to rerun the php artisan serve, sorry if im wrong before..
actually i don't really find any issue anymore, it should have solve it using   `{{route('store')}}` @BenjaminBrasseur

Comment: @Vynart I already tried to change action="{{ route ('store')}}" and is the same problem. But thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Add @csrf token below the `<form method='post' action=''>`. Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Add it where specifically?

Answer (score -1):

You must first create a route as already has been said before. In your Web routes add the line

```
Route::post("store", "test@store")->name('store');
```

And change your form post action to

```
{{route('store')}}
```

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: Done that already, the page shows. But when I press the "Add product" still says (1/1) NotFoundHttpException